# Gradle: How to create a library from only part of a project?

Tags: java, gradle

I have a spring boot project with server functionality. In the same project I wrote a client that provides an abstract way of communicating with the server. The client makes it much easier to make the necessary HTTP requests without needing to be concerned with URLS, response codes, etc.

I would like for the client code to live in the server project, and export this as a library that I can add as a gradle dependency in other projects.

What is the best way to do this? Can I configure gradle to export a certain package as a separate library, e.g. com.example.client.* or do I need a second build.gradle and re-structure the project?

Comment: You can go for gradle modules

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation for

- [Multi Project Builds](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html)
- [Publishing Artifacts](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/artifact_management.html)